# php datetime using existing date to create new date with added days

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date:

```
$launched=new DateTime();
```

I would like to create a new DateTime using $launched but adding days. Something like:

```
$expired=new DateTime($launched->modify("+$expiry days"));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP 5.5 or newer [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) makes this easy:

```
$launched = new DateTimeImmutable();
$expired  = $launched->modify("+$expiry days");
```

`DateTimeImmutable` does not modify the original object which is what `DateTime` does. So you can just assign the resulting object return by `modify()` to a variable and have a new object with a date in the future.

If you are using an older, and obsolete, version of PHP you can clone the original object to achieve the same result:

```
$launched = new DateTimeImmutable();
$expired  = clone $launched;
$expired->modify("+$expiry days");
```